# Algorithm to get all possible forms of a word with varying suffixes

Tags: algorithms, strings, dictionary

I'm writing an application in javascript where given a word, I need to get all the possible versions of the word with the suffix being the difference between each form. For example:

"sponsor" should return "sponsorship", "sponsoring", "sponsors", etc

"spy" should return "spies", "spying", "spied", etc.

I thought of having a list of common suffixes and then attaching each suffix to the given word and checking in the dictionary if the resulting word exists or not. But the problem with that is, sometimes the last one or two letter of the initial word need to be changed before the suffix can be added. Like for "spy", the "y" needs to be replaced with "i" before adding "es" to get "spies". I googled a lot and didn't find much help. All I could find was [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nltk-users/mw5Bu1dKtb4) with a python program attached at the end that's not making any sense to me.

If someone could suggest me an algorithm for this or explain the logic of the python program, that'd be really helpful.

Comment: There's no magic algorithm here. You're basically going to have to identify special cases (like words ending in Y) and treat them accordingly. English language rules are not systematic, there are a lot of exceptions like the one you pointed out.

Comment: @Adrian You're right. After posting this question I googled a bit and was able to find a list of special cases you need to watchout for while adding suffixes. That was all I needed. Though some very super rare exceptions might be left out it will be good enough for me.

Comment: The list of special cases will be longer than the basic rule set. For example, for die, you would want to include dying, but for part, you would not include partying. For rise, you have to strip all the way back to the "r" to match rose, but you take no letters of die to match died. Whilst there are only a handful of verbs that are irregular in the present tense, there are nearly 200 commonly used verbs that are irregular in the past tense. Each has to be handled independently, rather than by simple "replace y with ie" etc spelling rules. The list will go on and on.

Comment: @HarshaReaper Do you need to handle tenses of verbs too? "spy" -> "spied" is fine but does "fly" -> "flew" count as a suffix? By the way, what you're trying to do is called [morphological derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphological_derivation) and is the exact opposite of [stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming), so it might be useful to look at approaches to both.

Comment: Consider to post what you found as an answer to your own question, together with a short explanation.

Comment: @DavidArno I only needed to get words ending with different suffixes while the words belonged to the same context. So there was no need for me to get "partying" from "part", "rose" from "rise", etc. What I needed was more like "parts" from "part", "rising" from "rise", etc which I was able to do by going through the rules for special cases before adding the "s", "ing", etc suffixes.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I finally ended up doing. I found a list of rules on [this link](http://resources.mysparklebox.co.uk/6000-7000/sb6260.pdf) that you need to follow when adding a suffix to a word.

For example, when the word ends with "y", you replace the "y" with "i" unless the suffix you're adding is "ing". When the word ends with "e" you might have to drop the "e" if your suffix begins with a vowel and so on.

And I have a list of some common suffixes like this:

```
var suffixes = [
    'er',
    'ing',
    'ship',
    'ment',
    'al',
    'es',
    's',
    'ery',
    'ion',
    'ive',
    'able',
    'or',
    'ible',
    'ic',
    'ant',
    'ancy',
    'y',
    'ed'
];
```

I just looped through each suffix, added it to the word while following the rules, checked if the resulting word existed in the dictionary and if it did, I added it to the results.